# White spots on Ocimum tenuiflorum leaves (chlorosis?)

Tags: diseases, leaves, basil

I'm growing Ocimum tenuiflorum (O. sanctum) from seed. Since 1 week ago, some seedlings have white spots on the leaves. I didn't see any insect or so and the spots look like a “depigmentation” of the leaves. What could it be? What should I do?

[image: White spots Ocimum tenuiflorum]
[image: White spots Ocimum tenuiflorum]

Comment: Not chlorosis, because chlorosis starts with the area between the veins getting lighter and the veins “stand out” as dark areas. Stab in the dark: fungus?

Comment: Those areas look more like deposits on the leaf than depigmentation - get a magnifying glass  and look closely. Could be an infestation (eggs or nymphs of some insect or something similar) or, yes, fungus of some sort. Pick a leaf and see if you can scrape it off....

Comment: @Bamboo can't scrape it off, neither did I see anything like eggs or so.
The spots are only on the top side of the leaves. The bottom side is clean and looks normal.

Comment: If the undersides look normal, its not 'depigmentation'. Not sure what it is - if its fungal, evidence should appear beneath the leaves and that might develop over time, but I'd be inclined to spray it with an insecticidal soap  mix, or maybe dilute neem